# Fitness based ranking

Tags: probability, logic

If 3 variables $x[0]$, $x[1]$, $x[2]$ and their sum give the probability of the variable being selected as follows

$$\begin{align}
p[0] &= \frac{\text{sum}-x[0]}{2\times\text{sum}}\\
p[1] &= \frac{\text{sum}-x[1]}{2\times\text{sum}}\\
p[2] &= \frac{\text{sum}-x[2]}{2\times\text{sum}}
\end{align}$$

then, it is not a very good fitness based probability. because for the numbers $0.426, 0.036, 0.325$ the corresponding probabilities are $0.23, 0.48, 0.29$, although the second number is 10 times smaller than the other two, it only receives half the share.

Can someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[assuming I understood what you meant] use Exponential ranking: $p_j = \frac{e^{- \alpha x_j}}{\sum_j e^{- \alpha x_j}}$

Where $\alpha$ is a coefficient $>1$ if you need to increase the 'weight' of the individual with the lower value

Comment: Well, I tried your approach but the answers are pretty much the same. `0.279, 0.412, 0.308` for the probability which is actually the opposite effect. Instead of increasing the share of the second number it decreased it.

Comment: Add coefficients as per edit

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now I just have to decide on a suitable coefficient